# How to place the x-axis of chart at the top instead bottom?

Tags: chart.js

I want the x-axis of the my chart to be at the top.

I will attach the source code.

Please help me.

current chart :
[image: current chart]

what I want :
[image: wanted chart]

```html
      borderSkipped: false,
      indexAxis: 'y',
      // aspectRatio: 4,
      scales: {
        y: {          
          beginAtZero: true
          // suggestedMax: 24,          
        },
        x: {          
          suggestedMax: 24,          
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1            
          }
        }        
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding to scales.x.position : ‘top’